# Can't add new function to models/table class in django (python)

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's the issue I'm currently having:

- I'm running through [the first django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) on Windows using Command Prompt
- I've created a table called 'Question' in models.py.
- I'm attempting to create a `__str__()` function within this class like following:

.

```
from django.db import models
class Question(models.Model):
   def __str__(self):
     return self.question_text`
```

This is how my models.py looks:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The error I'm receiving is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
kwargs = {"app_label": package_components[app_label_index]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Anyone got any idea? I'm a total noob to django, and I'm not 100% sure what base.py should be doing here.

Base.py can be found here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there

you need to add the `def __str__()` method inside of the Question class inside of models.py file like.

your models.py should look like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text #or whatever u want here, i just guessed u wanted choice text
```

what you are actually doing is overriding a built in dunder method in a class you are subclassing. `models.Model` itself has a `__str__` method inside it already, and you are just modifying its behavior in your `Question` version of `models.Model`

PS. the method name should be `__unicode__` instead of `__str__` if you are on python 2

PPS. a little bit of OOP language: if a "function" is part of a class, it is called a "method"

Comment: it happens, check out [this](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/) article on sublcassing/inheritance, because often it helps to see WHY you are doing something to understand why its not working